# IText 7 flatten PDF

Tags: itext7

Is It possible to flatten AcroForm fields via PushButton or Button field in IText7.
For example; User downloaded PDF file then filled forms and flatten it via button.
Thanks.

Comment: No. Itext 7 is a java/.net library, it's flattering code is java/.net code. But when a button is pressed, the pdf is displayed in a viewer which usually does not know java/.net. A pdf viewer may run *javascript* code, though, in reaction to a button being pushed (not all viewers do but in particular Adobe Reader does). Thus, you may want to change your question to ask for javascript code for form flattening in a pdf viewer. Such javascript code you can embed into your pdf using itext. I don't know, though, if javascript in pdfs actually can flatten forms.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Maybe I have to be more clear. Thanks,
Finally I found a solution. Maybe somebody need;
Create action below;
    PdfAction action=PdfAction.CreateJavaScript("for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {var fname = this.getNthFieldName(i); if(fname!='Post') this.getField(fname).readonly = true;}");
Then add this action to a Push Button;

Comment: Your code sets the read only flag to true. That is not the same as flattening.